# Updating Consumer usernames in Kong

Tags: node.js, kong

I have a node application that routes API calls to update usernames to our kong layer. Whenever I try to update a consumer with a username that has previously been used, but *is NO LONGER IN USE*, kong throws an error about not being able to create a kong JWT for that consumer. For some reason, kong is not allowing these old usernames to be freed up after theyve been updated/are no longer in use by a consumer. Any idea as to what kong might be doing and how to remedy this? I'd like to be able to update a consumer's username, and then update it back to the previous username without errors being thrown. I have  a feeling this is inherent to the way kong works but havent had much luck in the documentation.

This is my request to kong when attempting to update a consumer

```
function updateConsumer(obj) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    if (useKong === 'true') {
      request(
        {
          url: kongAdminUrl+'/consumers/'+obj.consumerId,
          method: 'PATCH',
          json: {
            'username': obj.userName,
            'custom_id': obj.spid
          }
        }, function(err,response,body) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          else {
            if (isDefined(body) && (typeof body) == 'string') body = JSON.parse(body);
            if (isDefined(body.id)) {
              obj.consumerId = body.id;
              console.log('Updated consumer \''+obj.userName+'\'');
              resolve(obj);
            } else {
              console.log('ERROR updating consumer \''+obj.userName+'\'');
              reject(new Error('failed to update kong consumer \''+obj.userName+'\''));
            }
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      // Not using kong
      resolve(obj);
    }
  });
}
```

the error I get is

```
{ key: 'already exists with value \'<username>\'' }
```

Is there some way to clear out the key in kong once a consumer is no longer actively using it?

**EDIT**: 
Okay so I think Ive figured out that the consumer is actually being updated, but the next step where Im trying to add a JWT is failing. Kong is finding the old JWT with the key of the old username thats trying to be added again, seeing that old JWT and not allowing two JWT’s with the same key to be added. So it seems like I need to delete the old JWT when updating the consumer.

```
function addConsumerJwtToken(obj) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    if (useKong === 'true') {
      request(
        {
          url: kongAdminUrl+'/consumers/'+obj.consumerId+'/jwt',
          method: 'POST',
          json: {
            'algorithm':'HS256',
            'key': obj.userName,
            'secret': obj.secret
          }
        }, function(err,response,body) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          else {
            if (isDefined(body) && (typeof body) == 'string') body = JSON.parse(body);
            if (isDefined(body.id)) {
              obj.jwtId = body.id;
              console.log('Added JWT token for consumer \''+obj.userName+'\'');
              resolve(obj);
            } else {
              console.log('ERROR adding JWT token for consumer \''+obj.userName+'\'');
              //console.log(obj);
              //console.log(response);
              reject(new Error('failed to create kong jwt for \''+obj.userName+'\''));
            }
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      // Not using kong
      resolve(obj);
    }
  });
}
```

I’ve thrown a deleteConsumerJWT in my promise chain to handle this before trying to add the new JWT, but to no avail. Still get the key already exists error, though my delete function seems to be functioning as expected and does not return any errors upon the delete request…

```
function deleteConsumerJwtToken(obj, oldJwt) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    if (useKong === 'true') {
      request(
        {
          url: kongAdminUrl+'/consumers/'+obj.consumerId+'/jwt'/oldJwt,
          method: 'DELETE',
        }, function(err,response,body) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          else {
            console.log('Deleted consumer jwt ' + oldJwt);
            resolve(obj);
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      // Not using kong
      resolve(obj);
    }
  });
}
```